# JavaScript generators and their prototype chains

Tags: javascript, generator, prototype

I am toying around with JavaScript generators and have 2 questions based on the following code and its output:

```
const a = function*(){}(); // Object [Generator] {}
const b = a.__proto__;     // Object [Generator] {}
const c = b.__proto__;     // Object [Generator] {}
const d = c.__proto__;     // {}
const e = d.__proto__;     // {}
const f = e.__proto__;     // null
console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f);
```

#### Question 1

It seems like every generator object has its own unique prototype, and they all share a common prototype:

```
const x = function*(){}();
const y = x.__proto__;
const z = y.__proto__;
console.log(b === y); // false
console.log(c === z); // true
```

Is my above understanding correct?

#### Question 2

Since `f` is `null`, `e` is probably `Object.prototype`:

```
console.log(e === Object.prototype); // true
```

However, I can't figure out what `d` is. Is there a `Something.prototype` that is equal to `d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the section [GeneratorFunction Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-generatorfunction-objects), there is a figure of the relationships:
[image: generator_objects_relationships]

### Question 1

Yes.

### Question 2

`d` is an [IteratorPrototype](http://Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(%5B%5D%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()))). And by the doc:

> The following expression is one way that ECMAScript code can access
> the %IteratorPrototype% object:
>
> ```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([][Symbol.iterator]()))
> ```

It seems that there is not an `Iterator` such that `Iterator.prototype` is equal to `d`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let's break this down some more:

```js
function* g() {} // a generator function
const GeneratorFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(g).constructor;
console.assert(Object.getPrototypeOf(GeneratorFunction) == Function);
const Generator = GeneratorFunction.prototype;
console.assert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Generator) == Function.prototype);
const ArrayIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf([].values());

const a = g(); // a generator
console.assert(a instanceof g);

const b = Object.getPrototypeOf(a); // a prototype object
console.assert(b == g.prototype);

const c = Object.getPrototypeOf(b); // the Generator.prototype
console.assert(c == Generator.prototype);

const d = Object.getPrototypeOf(c); // the Iterator.prototype
console.assert(d == Object.getPrototypeOf(ArrayIteratorPrototype));

const e = Object.getPrototypeOf(d); // the Object.prototype
console.assert(e == Object.prototype);

const f = Object.getPrototypeOf(e); // null
console.assert(f == null);
```

The object `d` you were looking for is the prototype object shared by all iterators (array iterators, map iterators, set iterators, string iterators etc), including generators. There is not global `Iterator` ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)) just as there are no global `Generator` or `GeneratorFunction`.